# Not in scope: readMaybe, which library should I import?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-platform, option-type

I'm trying to use the function readMaybe, which should be in the Text.Read library, but when I compile I receive this message:

```
 Module `Text.Read' does not export `readMaybe'
```

Can anyone say me what am I doing wrong? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `readMaybe` was added in ghc-7.6.1 (or `base-4.6.0.0`). Perhaps you're using an older version of GHC?

Comment: Yes, that could be the problem. Thanks ;)